# HSC Cycling Rates

Tags: cell-biology, hematology

I would like to know how often human hematopoietic stem cells go into cycle in the bone marrow niche (with a paper reference). I have heard they cycle 1-2 times per year but has anyone robustly measured this?

Comment: Not knowledgeable in this respect myself, is this what I should be looking for? http://www.bloodjournal.org/content/117/17/4460?sso-checked=true

Comment: That is helpful but I would like something where the dynamics are directly measured if it has been done.